# NSString concatinate NSInteger Frozen

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

My IOS app needs to put a number behind a string.
The number is received by the index of the cell that is being pushed.
however if i run the app and push a cell.
My screen goes to xCode showing that there is a variable called tempstring. the simulator however does not respond anymore..
How can i fix this?
This is the code i use:

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *tempstring = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.app-creater.com/service.php?k=%i",indexPath.row];
    NSLog(tempstring);
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Retrieve cell
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // Get the location to be shown
    Location *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];

    // Get references to labels of cell
    myCell.textLabel.text = item.Name;

    return myCell;
}
```

I get a thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 at the NSlog(tempstring)
Saying incomplete format specifier.

How can i fix this?

-EDIT-

What i want to achieve is to get the string:
"www.app-create.com/service.php?k=1" (or any number)
with that string i want to download a partial JSON piece so in example the Password piece, corresponding to the string number.
so for example that link is for the email address: tet@icloud.com, i get the password 1234, for the link www.app-create.com/service.php?k=0, i get password 4321

Comment: That's two different things, a breakpoint and a compiler warning. Fix the compiler warning and remove the breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks... i don't know what happened. Rookie mistake >.>'

Comment: This question is similar to the “Thread 1: stopped at breakpoint” error when initializing an NSURL object.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `NSLog` without **format specifier**.

Change :

```
NSLog(tempstring);
```

to

```
NSLog(@"%@",tempstring);
```

According to [**this**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html) apple documentation, your code may crash due to `signal 10 (SIGBUS)`

Comment: Of course you can, if `tempstring` does not contain any `%` format specifiers. (That does not mean that you should.)

Comment: Even when changing it it does not work. i also removed the NSLog(), and it stil freezes up. i think it has something to do with declaring a variable

Comment: @MartinR: If I'm wrong please let me know the answer. According to this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) NSLog calls NSLogv it expects a format specifier.

Comment: If I see it correctly, `tempstring` is computed as (for example) `@"http://www.app-creater.com/service.php?k=5"`. Then `NSLog(temp string)` will work. It would crash if `tempstring` contained any `%` characters which NSLog would try to replace by (non-existing) arguments).

Comment: You are completely right that you *should* always use `NSLog(@"%@",temp string);`. I just don't see how this would cause a crash in this particular question.

Comment: @MartinR: I mainly concentrated on the following part of the question `NSlog(tempstring) Saying incomplete format specifier.`

Comment: That's fine, and as it seems, there was no crash at all, only a breakpoint and a compiler warning. But *"your code will cause a crash ..."* is wrong. It causes the warning, and it *might* crash, depending on what tempstring contains.

Comment: @MartinR: Yeah, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of NSLog is as fellows:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
```

So you can't write a statement like:

```
NSLog(tempstring);
```

You always need to use a format string and pass in the arguments that you want - to be part of the NSString like following:

```
NSLog(@"The value of tempstring is: %@", tempstring);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure '%i' is a valid format specifier. you might have to use '%d' or one of the ones specified here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

Comment: `%i` and `%d` are both valid and equivalent.